# Is it possible to get the majority color of an emoji?

Tags: javascript, css, shadow, emoji

What I'm trying to achieve is adding a `text-shadow` to an emoji with the `text-shadow` color being the most prominent color in the emoji.

I know there are JavaScript libraries that identify the most prominent color in images, but since the emoji is technically text I'm not sure how I'd do it or even if it's possible at all.

I would provide some code for what I've already tried, but quite honestly, I wouldn't even know where to start.

```css
.emoji {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(54, 169, 230, 0.65);
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<span class="emoji"></span>
```

Comment: If you can do it with an image, make the emoji into an image by drawing it on a canvas.

Comment: some useful tools : http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/ http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative approach without using `text-shadow` is to copy the emoji, place it directly behind the original and blur it.

You could create the copy directly in the HTML, or if easier use js, as in the example below.

```js
var emoji = document.querySelector("#blur-me");
var copy = emoji.cloneNode(true);
copy.classList.remove("emoji");
emoji.appendChild(copy);
```

```css
.emoji {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.emoji span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<span class="emoji" id="blur-me"></span>
```

Answer (score 13):

An alternative answser to the one proposed by [@Sol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012317/8620333) is to use an attribute to duplicate the icon without the need of JS. You can also apply a scale transformation to make the effect more visible:

```css
.emoji {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin:0 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}
.emoji:before,
.emoji:after{
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
.emoji:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<span class="emoji" data-icon=""></span>
<span class="emoji" data-icon=""></span>
<span class="emoji" data-icon=""></span>
<span class="emoji" data-icon=""></span>
```

Comment: I love avoiding the use of JS when possible. @JaneDoe – consider the possibility that not everyone has JavaScript enabled; the drop shadow would still work for those users doing it this way.

Comment: @ianrandmckenzie yes I realize, I just meant that the answer was the best solution for me. Others might find css better.

Answer (score 3):

The approach of blurring a copy of the emoji (as proposed by sol) is a valid and fairly lightweight approach. Tweaking it a bit you can get something that is more shadow like:

```js
var emoji = document.querySelector("#blur-me");
var copy = emoji.cloneNode(true);
copy.classList.remove("emoji");
emoji.appendChild(copy);
```

```css
.emoji {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.emoji span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: scale(.95) translate(5px, 5px);
}
```

```html
<span class="emoji" id="blur-me"></span>
```

The `scale(.95)` is to compensate for the blur growing it, and then the `translate()` is simply to shift it over more like a text shadow and less like a blur.

Another approach which would let you get a more exactly color would be to draw it to a canvas. Once you have a canvas, its basically an image, so those libraries you mentioned could work.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 30;
canvas.height = 30;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillText("", 0, 20);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.emoji {
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Once you have that, there are a couple different ways you can get the average. One would be to just get the raw pixels, exclude the background color, and then just mathematically average the remainder. Since canvas is non-transparent, you could use the old-school trick of filling with a really ugly color:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 30;
canvas.height = 30;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#121212'; // 12 => 17 in decimal
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillText("", 0, 20);

const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// an array in the format [r, g, b, count] decimal
const sums = imageData.data.reduce((r, v, i) => {
   if (v === 18) return r; // our fill color, skip
   if (i % 4 !== 3) { // i % 4 === 3 is transparent, ignoring
     r[i % 4] += v;
     r[3]++;
   }
   
   return r;
}, [0, 0, 0, 0]);

sums[3] = sums[3] / 3; // divide by 3 since we counted each pixel 3 times
const averages = [Math.floor(sums[0] / sums[3]), Math.floor(sums[1] / sums[3]), Math.floor(sums[2] / sums[3])];

// just to see the color
ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${averages.join(',')})`;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.emoji {
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Obviously, this particular algorithm is pretty basic and not perfect (mainly for demo purposes). There are other algorithms or libraries. If you call `canvas.toDataUrl()` you'll even get a value you can use like an image in most libraries.

From there, just take the calculated color and just use JavaScript to set it to the `element.style.textShadow` attribute.

```js
document.querySelector('.emoji').style.textShadow = 'rgb(255, 0, 0) 2px 2px';
```

```html
<span class="emoji"></span>
```

Comment: but what about if the prominent color is mostly inside the icon? I think we should not only focus on prominent color but maybe consider prominent color that are more close to the edge in order to have a shadow which the continuity of the emoji

Comment: There are all different ways you could slice and dice it to extract a color. I didn't try to answer that question, because there are lots of different approaches and algorithms for it. I just tried to answer how you can turn it into an image so you can use those libraries out there. I just provided one as an example approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this for any future fellow programist that will have to tackle this problem.

Down below there's full javascript Object of emojis and their main color.

It looks like : EMOJIS[ "emojiUnicode" ] = hexColor

```
const EMOJIS = {
    8986: "#6e6bbd",
    8987: "#a6a48b",
    9193: "#30aee3",
    9194: "#30aee4",
    9195: "#30aee3",
    9196: "#30aee3",
    9197: "#39b1e4",
    9198: "#38b0e4",
    9199: "#2faee5",
    9200: "#cd8a76",
    9201: "#aca5a5",
    9202: "#5a98b3",
    9203: "#a8a68c",
    9208: "#23a9e3",
    9209: "#51b9e6",
    9210: "#40b3e5",
    9748: "#5e5999",
    9749: "#a6938e",
    9757: "#e1b938",
    9800: "#9575c2",
    9801: "#9676c3",
    9802: "#9879c4",
    9803: "#9f82c7",
    9804: "#997ac4",
    9805: "#9f82c7",
    9806: "#9676c3",
    9807: "#9b7cc5",
    9808: "#9372c1",
    9809: "#9a7bc5",
    9810: "#9575c2",
    9811: "#9676c3",
    9855: "#25aae3",
    9875: "#0579ab",
    9889: "#ca6926",
    9898: "#dedede",
    9899: "#010101",
    9917: "#95a5dc",
    9918: "#cfc3c3",
    9924: "#a2b1c0",
    9925: "#d8c2ad",
    9934: "#9778c3",
    9940: "#e54846",
    9962: "#998162",
    9970: "#8793a9",
    9971: "#627c30",
    9973: "#79917c",
    9977: "#a6723d",
    9978: "#75a827",
    9981: "#b85150",
    9989: "#18ca72",
    9994: "#e6bc38",
    9995: "#e2bb39",
    9996: "#e0b837",
    9997: "#dc9f37",
    10024: "#be9530",
    10060: "#c8284f",
    10062: "#25cd7a",
    10067: "#b72726",
    10068: "#86808c",
    10069: "#847e8a",
    10071: "#b42726",
    10133: "#544c7d",
    10134: "#544b7c",
    10135: "#514979",
    10160: "#49426c",
    10175: "#433d61",
    11035: "#0d0d0d",
    11036: "#dddddd",
    11088: "#e1be39",
    11093: "#cd2951",
    126980: "#d0a8c3",
    127183: "#cbc0ca",
    127344: "#ec4c73",
    127345: "#ed5379",
    127358: "#ec4c73",
    127359: "#22a9e3",
    127374: "#ed5c7f",
    127377: "#ec4b72",
    127378: "#1ba6e2",
    127379: "#21a8e2",
    127380: "#9b7cc5",
    127381: "#1fa8e2",
    127382: "#38b1e4",
    127383: "#34afe4",
    127384: "#ec4f75",
    127385: "#28abe3",
    127386: "#f18a43",
    127489: "#2aace3",
    127514: "#f19c62",
    127535: "#46d38d",
    127538: "#ed5f81",
    127539: "#37b0e4",
    127540: "#ed557a",
    127541: "#ed6787",
    127542: "#f19658",
    127544: "#f19455",
    127545: "#ed6c8c",
    127546: "#f19c61",
    127568: "#e76786",
    127569: "#eb8e4f",
    127744: "#0f3c98",
    127745: "#a9b6bc",
    127746: "#745398",
    127747: "#5a526a",
    127748: "#8d7b51",
    127749: "#ba8e80",
    127750: "#76608d",
    127751: "#946560",
    127752: "#9f8362",
    127753: "#723f69",
    127754: "#1f9fd1",
    127755: "#7c5156",
    127756: "#1a4a7b",
    127757: "#01908d",
    127758: "#018795",
    127759: "#018b91",
    127760: "#6296bb",
    127761: "#472d58",
    127762: "#6e5051",
    127763: "#967648",
    127764: "#ba9742",
    127765: "#e8c23a",
    127766: "#cfa955",
    127767: "#b38d74",
    127768: "#9d778c",
    127769: "#d1ae35",
    127770: "#845c9c",
    127771: "#caa736",
    127772: "#d0ac38",
    127773: "#dab53a",
    127774: "#d69a34",
    127775: "#c4a734",
    127776: "#86684d",
    127789: "#db8941",
    127790: "#c59e30",
    127791: "#bba079",
    127792: "#895d3d",
    127793: "#66802a",
    127794: "#3f781b",
    127795: "#41811a",
    127796: "#627d27",
    127797: "#6bab26",
    127799: "#c16788",
    127800: "#e26bb4",
    127801: "#b94a2c",
    127802: "#d55890",
    127803: "#97872f",
    127804: "#abb089",
    127805: "#8c992a",
    127806: "#5e671f",
    127807: "#548921",
    127808: "#02b05b",
    127809: "#c6242d",
    127810: "#c34832",
    127811: "#16975a",
    127812: "#dc6252",
    127813: "#9e5b41",
    127814: "#6d4f97",
    127815: "#4b4257",
    127816: "#9ca86a",
    127817: "#a05a4d",
    127818: "#d07b2e",
    127819: "#c8bb3c",
    127820: "#d9c05d",
    127821: "#bf9748",
    127822: "#d13930",
    127823: "#71c430",
    127824: "#a0d139",
    127825: "#cb7c2f",
    127826: "#a95228",
    127827: "#984e37",
    127828: "#a47b3c",
    127829: "#da9842",
    127830: "#8a5f56",
    127831: "#b3804f",
    127832: "#b28160",
    127833: "#a29ba7",
    127834: "#d8878d",
    127835: "#ca9c7f",
    127836: "#b83e37",
    127837: "#c89c6b",
    127838: "#deab6d",
    127839: "#de5633",
    127840: "#e4523f",
    127841: "#91b484",
    127842: "#a78378",
    127843: "#e58874",
    127844: "#dc8526",
    127845: "#d4c2cb",
    127846: "#d6ae79",
    127847: "#9f8fb5",
    127848: "#839c9e",
    127849: "#80573f",
    127850: "#cc9053",
    127851: "#99424f",
    127852: "#cf562d",
    127853: "#9a8678",
    127854: "#bd9572",
    127855: "#9f6530",
    127856: "#daa264",
    127857: "#665958",
    127858: "#b98977",
    127859: "#645c7d",
    127860: "#756d7d",
    127861: "#8a8b88",
    127862: "#a2a7bb",
    127863: "#a17fb3",
    127864: "#8ba983",
    127865: "#ad8261",
    127866: "#c6be8e",
    127867: "#b9b289",
    127868: "#dec2af",
    127870: "#74863c",
    127871: "#e28a68",
    127872: "#cc2034",
    127873: "#dc7a38",
    127874: "#d1a76d",
    127875: "#c8694c",
    127876: "#58761e",
    127877: "#cda282",
    127878: "#6f4a59",
    127879: "#6c4f5e",
    127880: "#c9313b",
    127881: "#66586f",
    127882: "#87614c",
    127883: "#537338",
    127884: "#a48f99",
    127885: "#7c8e3f",
    127886: "#7c6c72",
    127887: "#726465",
    127888: "#7b9ebb",
    127889: "#745c50",
    127890: "#df382e",
    127891: "#4d3040",
    127904: "#b87d45",
    127905: "#816f6d",
    127906: "#6a453c",
    127907: "#406d75",
    127908: "#756b7b",
    127909: "#635b87",
    127910: "#43b4e5",
    127911: "#86808d",
    127912: "#cd9997",
    127913: "#55294d",
    127914: "#b76e85",
    127915: "#dba837",
    127916: "#5e487f",
    127917: "#608674",
    127918: "#523c65",
    127919: "#be7c86",
    127920: "#aea4b0",
    127921: "#5c5778",
    127922: "#bfb5c5",
    127923: "#a096a6",
    127924: "#ae3182",
    127925: "#534b7b",
    127926: "#4e4673",
    127927: "#c09b39",
    127928: "#9c5170",
    127929: "#928d95",
    127930: "#b38035",
    127931: "#633d39",
    127932: "#918b98",
    127933: "#5a8d1f",
    127934: "#7f4b45",
    127935: "#527d85",
    127936: "#c95420",
    127937: "#787878",
    127938: "#95a4ae",
    127939: "#9e7535",
    127940: "#826c66",
    127941: "#b58b4c",
    127942: "#a7712c",
    127943: "#53533e",
    127944: "#81675c",
    127945: "#e6a036",
    127946: "#5f8e8b",
    127947: "#8e6544",
    127948: "#836344",
    127951: "#af7851",
    127952: "#c7c7c7",
    127953: "#8c6b6d",
    127954: "#9a6f61",
    127955: "#cb5372",
    127968: "#b38d67",
    127969: "#859664",
    127970: "#a8b4bd",
    127971: "#ab969c",
    127972: "#ac9b9e",
    127973: "#a895a8",
    127974: "#949295",
    127975: "#17a5e2",
    127976: "#d7ac90",
    127977: "#d98a8b",
    127978: "#aa8f9c",
    127979: "#c1a57b",
    127980: "#7393af",
    127981: "#a09194",
    127982: "#c4463d",
    127983: "#bc606a",
    127984: "#9e7688",
    127988: "#0f0f0f",
    127992: "#385b73",
    127993: "#836a58",
    127994: "#845126",
    128000: "#6f595a",
    128001: "#b79ca8",
    128002: "#875844",
    128003: "#505050",
    128004: "#8d8888",
    128005: "#b96832",
    128006: "#cb8c2c",
    128007: "#cfcaca",
    128008: "#c08b50",
    128009: "#448e53",
    128010: "#0daf57",
    128011: "#359fd0",
    128012: "#a46e49",
    128013: "#11a754",
    128014: "#6d483a",
    128015: "#b09c97",
    128016: "#b9854e",
    128017: "#b09f9f",
    128018: "#6d4639",
    128019: "#7c5b2d",
    128020: "#d9b9b3",
    128021: "#be874d",
    128022: "#d87574",
    128023: "#70473a",
    128024: "#929292",
    128025: "#da664e",
    128026: "#a2a2a2",
    128027: "#049d54",
    128028: "#4c426c",
    128029: "#7d6761",
    128030: "#742423",
    128031: "#0290cd",
    128032: "#4690ae",
    128033: "#d2966b",
    128034: "#229153",
    128035: "#ccbb85",
    128036: "#dab036",
    128037: "#d8af36",
    128038: "#ac173e",
    128039: "#aa96a1",
    128040: "#777777",
    128041: "#999999",
    128042: "#c68c4e",
    128043: "#c3894e",
    128044: "#0d8ec7",
    128045: "#bc98a3",
    128046: "#ab8d86",
    128047: "#c47c50",
    128048: "#aea0ae",
    128049: "#dc8d2e",
    128050: "#50935d",
    128051: "#339eca",
    128052: "#563b31",
    128053: "#9d6155",
    128054: "#b58862",
    128055: "#e38482",
    128056: "#72b94e",
    128057: "#d48d5c",
    128058: "#959595",
    128059: "#99634b",
    128060: "#a5a3b2",
    128061: "#be6767",
    128062: "#49436c",
    128064: "#ada8b0",
    128066: "#e2b837",
    128067: "#d9b639",
    128068: "#c9365e",
    128069: "#b11a6b",
    128070: "#e1bc3a",
    128071: "#e3bf3a",
    128072: "#ddb939",
    128073: "#dfbb39",
    128074: "#e9c039",
    128075: "#c0a643",
    128076: "#cfad36",
    128077: "#e3bc39",
    128078: "#deb838",
    128079: "#d6b33e",
    128080: "#d8b337",
    128081: "#cc9235",
    128082: "#cd7759",
    128083: "#6f89b0",
    128084: "#5d99d7",
    128085: "#78c12d",
    128086: "#0286c1",
    128087: "#3e8ad4",
    128088: "#2084c0",
    128089: "#ac184f",
    128090: "#e05bac",
    128091: "#e31d79",
    128092: "#996942",
    128093: "#e39a96",
    128094: "#895846",
    128095: "#908f96",
    128096: "#990f3f",
    128097: "#a84839",
    128098: "#c23550",
    128099: "#4f4875",
    128100: "#583870",
    128101: "#56376d",
    128102: "#deac38",
    128103: "#dfaa36",
    128104: "#dfaf39",
    128105: "#e4ab34",
    128106: "#dc8a32",
    128107: "#6a6b5d",
    128108: "#5a7264",
    128109: "#7b6457",
    128110: "#4e9294",
    128111: "#795f3d",
    128112: "#d4bf90",
    128113: "#e4c65e",
    128114: "#a8483e",
    128115: "#dbc379",
    128116: "#d7b448",
    128117: "#bca355",
    128118: "#dab43f",
    128119: "#dba643",
    128120: "#ab8362",
    128121: "#934360",
    128122: "#c24954",
    128123: "#d0c1cc",
    128124: "#c8b258",
    128125: "#70993f",
    128126: "#514876",
    128127: "#8854a1",
    128128: "#bab6b7",
    128129: "#d08129",
    128130: "#894149",
    128131: "#bb422d",
    128132: "#a73a67",
    128133: "#bf9955",
    128134: "#dc892c",
    128135: "#cf7a2e",
    128136: "#8a8897",
    128137: "#7aa3c9",
    128138: "#dd7936",
    128139: "#d12952",
    128140: "#d897b2",
    128141: "#6e8799",
    128142: "#36a3da",
    128143: "#d56f4d",
    128144: "#8d7e54",
    128145: "#d16054",
    128146: "#b87c79",
    128147: "#c6284e",
    128148: "#d32953",
    128149: "#d32953",
    128150: "#df3f53",
    128151: "#e36daf",
    128152: "#c73257",
    128153: "#0169a8",
    128154: "#01be60",
    128155: "#e3c03a",
    128156: "#805cb2",
    128157: "#df5f44",
    128158: "#c5284e",
    128159: "#a084c6",
    128160: "#0490cb",
    128161: "#ceb24a",
    128162: "#bb2826",
    128163: "#5e3b5b",
    128164: "#317fa5",
    128165: "#c03f29",
    128166: "#0388c1",
    128167: "#23b2de",
    128168: "#cacaca",
    128169: "#905954",
    128170: "#e0bb39",
    128171: "#b78a2c",
    128172: "#d7d7d7",
    128173: "#d7d7d7",
    128174: "#e7c7da",
    128175: "#b02625",
    128176: "#cb9e67",
    128177: "#26537b",
    128178: "#049950",
    128179: "#2e8fbe",
    128180: "#d4a35d",
    128181: "#2abf7b",
    128182: "#65a8c6",
    128183: "#a08fb1",
    128184: "#4eb681",
    128185: "#1aca73",
    128186: "#3582a9",
    128187: "#60accb",
    128188: "#7a4c39",
    128189: "#a3835b",
    128190: "#95819a",
    128191: "#b3adb9",
    128192: "#e5a62f",
    128193: "#ecc038",
    128194: "#ebbc36",
    128195: "#cfc9d5",
    128196: "#d3ced9",
    128197: "#9fbad4",
    128198: "#9fb6cf",
    128199: "#a0a3bf",
    128200: "#d2b8cd",
    128201: "#babfd7",
    128202: "#88acbf",
    128203: "#cfb7a4",
    128204: "#c2323d",
    128205: "#d13189",
    128206: "#5f5c5d",
    128207: "#9d9ba0",
    128208: "#a6a4a9",
    128209: "#ccc1cc",
    128210: "#dab948",
    128211: "#5b416c",
    128212: "#624775",
    128213: "#b6154a",
    128214: "#abc0d5",
    128215: "#71bc36",
    128216: "#0b95d4",
    128217: "#da552e",
    128218: "#618663",
    128219: "#e1476c",
    128220: "#e5c089",
    128221: "#d6b8b6",
    128222: "#c22638",
    128223: "#388e65",
    128224: "#666077",
    128225: "#7e8288",
    128226: "#bd5866",
    128227: "#d3a232",
    128228: "#7e9bba",
    128229: "#809cbc",
    128230: "#d5a161",
    128231: "#a4bad1",
    128232: "#a8aabc",
    128233: "#c9adc0",
    128234: "#546bc7",
    128235: "#546cc8",
    128236: "#7481ba",
    128237: "#525b99",
    128238: "#c64369",
    128239: "#b4832e",
    128240: "#b9b2c0",
    128241: "#594c5f",
    128242: "#515165",
    128243: "#f1a750",
    128244: "#f1a64d",
    128245: "#d27a79",
    128246: "#4bb7e5",
    128247: "#79738d",
    128248: "#807782",
    128249: "#858095",
    128250: "#768698",
    128251: "#777e83",
    128252: "#746491",
    128255: "#bc8751",
    128256: "#2bace3",
    128257: "#30aee3",
    128258: "#30aee3",
    128259: "#36b0e4",
    128260: "#4d4672",
    128261: "#a37222",
    128262: "#ab7723",
    128263: "#bb8f9b",
    128264: "#b5adbd",
    128265: "#aba8ba",
    128266: "#9a9fb2",
    128267: "#86be49",
    128268: "#563a58",
    128269: "#2c77af",
    128270: "#2c76ae",
    128271: "#b19a57",
    128272: "#ba994e",
    128273: "#cb9e33",
    128274: "#c9a143",
    128275: "#c59e42",
    128276: "#deac36",
    128277: "#db8f33",
    128278: "#cf3533",
    128279: "#828282",
    128280: "#8a8091",
    128281: "#4b446f",
    128282: "#4d4672",
    128283: "#4a436d",
    128284: "#49426c",
    128285: "#4c4570",
    128286: "#c46c6b",
    128287: "#3eb3e4",
    128288: "#33afe4",
    128289: "#2dade3",
    128290: "#26aae3",
    128291: "#33afe4",
    128292: "#1da6e1",
    128293: "#e27b25",
    128294: "#887a77",
    128295: "#8b8591",
    128296: "#7c605e",
    128297: "#9890a0",
    128298: "#8d8798",
    128299: "#aa8f2f",
    128300: "#838992",
    128301: "#6e6b89",
    128302: "#6b536a",
    128303: "#9879c4",
    128304: "#969e29",
    128305: "#bd8225",
    128306: "#999999",
    128307: "#595959",
    128308: "#e42e2c",
    128309: "#016bab",
    128310: "#e45d20",
    128311: "#0168a7",
    128312: "#d1561f",
    128313: "#036099",
    128314: "#c52928",
    128315: "#ce2b29",
    128316: "#29abe3",
    128317: "#29abe3",
    128331: "#614248",
    128332: "#86745a",
    128333: "#a17d53",
    128334: "#9f82c7",
    128336: "#a19d9e",
    128337: "#a19d9e",
    128338: "#a09c9e",
    128339: "#a19c9e",
    128340: "#a19c9e",
    128341: "#a09c9d",
    128342: "#a09c9e",
    128343: "#a09c9e",
    128344: "#a09c9d",
    128345: "#a19c9e",
    128346: "#a09d9e",
    128347: "#a19f9f",
    128348: "#a19c9e",
    128349: "#a19c9e",
    128350: "#a09c9d",
    128351: "#a19c9e",
    128352: "#a19d9e",
    128353: "#a19f9f",
    128354: "#a09d9e",
    128355: "#a09c9e",
    128356: "#a09c9d",
    128357: "#a09c9e",
    128358: "#a09c9d",
    128359: "#a09c9d",
    128372: "#5f475d",
    128373: "#7d6a6d",
    128378: "#426c79",
    128400: "#deb938",
    128405: "#dab738",
    128406: "#dcb738",
    128420: "#101010",
    128507: "#5c476b",
    128508: "#b35d36",
    128509: "#388f79",
    128510: "#05954e",
    128511: "#a3a3a3",
    128512: "#d18a51",
    128513: "#dea456",
    128514: "#c38052",
    128515: "#ce884f",
    128516: "#d7883e",
    128517: "#cb834b",
    128518: "#d28142",
    128519: "#b8894b",
    128520: "#8853a0",
    128521: "#d69242",
    128522: "#d88e2b",
    128523: "#d78d30",
    128524: "#d7942b",
    128525: "#e16159",
    128526: "#a16f47",
    128527: "#db9e3c",
    128528: "#d4993c",
    128529: "#de992b",
    128530: "#dc9e3c",
    128531: "#cb913c",
    128532: "#da962b",
    128533: "#d49b41",
    128534: "#d2912b",
    128535: "#d5993c",
    128536: "#d58a3c",
    128537: "#dd982b",
    128538: "#d8912b",
    128539: "#d78c4d",
    128540: "#dc8d48",
    128541: "#dc893c",
    128542: "#da962b",
    128543: "#daa24a",
    128544: "#d8a048",
    128545: "#d34949",
    128546: "#cc9544",
    128547: "#d7952b",
    128548: "#d2a55d",
    128549: "#ca9448",
    128550: "#dfa14f",
    128551: "#da9a51",
    128552: "#ac8e87",
    128553: "#d3843d",
    128554: "#d1913b",
    128555: "#d1833d",
    128556: "#e1ac61",
    128557: "#ac866c",
    128558: "#dd9b52",
    128559: "#dda04d",
    128560: "#9d8e92",
    128561: "#c3957a",
    128562: "#dda150",
    128563: "#dd9d4a",
    128564: "#cc983b",
    128565: "#d48b31",
    128566: "#db9d3c",
    128567: "#deac68",
    128568: "#dc8d2e",
    128569: "#c88647",
    128570: "#dc8d2e",
    128571: "#d97b31",
    128572: "#db902a",
    128573: "#d8862d",
    128574: "#da902a",
    128575: "#d69133",
    128576: "#e49c46",
    128577: "#d4983c",
    128578: "#d4993c",
    128579: "#d4993d",
    128580: "#e1a84c",
    128581: "#de8824",
    128582: "#da7c2a",
    128583: "#d88f2e",
    128584: "#945e4f",
    128585: "#9b6153",
    128586: "#9b6555",
    128587: "#d8882d",
    128588: "#c7a93b",
    128589: "#db9130",
    128590: "#e39c2a",
    128591: "#aa787d",
    128640: "#bf7287",
    128641: "#a1794f",
    128642: "#8f5960",
    128643: "#7c9758",
    128644: "#84aec8",
    128645: "#7d9bb1",
    128646: "#547c95",
    128647: "#6a5c72",
    128648: "#8ba3a7",
    128649: "#588490",
    128650: "#797287",
    128651: "#86788f",
    128652: "#739188",
    128653: "#759596",
    128654: "#4a999f",
    128655: "#6296c0",
    128656: "#7492ac",
    128657: "#b2798f",
    128658: "#a16169",
    128659: "#667d8c",
    128660: "#628794",
    128661: "#939057",
    128662: "#a2a466",
    128663: "#915565",
    128664: "#80707a",
    128665: "#5183b8",
    128666: "#bd9652",
    128667: "#86a8a5",
    128668: "#1f9681",
    128669: "#4c93b8",
    128670: "#5dac80",
    128671: "#6497a5",
    128672: "#7a768a",
    128673: "#7b9476",
    128674: "#987b9f",
    128675: "#529f8a",
    128676: "#669198",
    128677: "#696654",
    128678: "#6a6653",
    128679: "#987a52",
    128680: "#c0685a",
    128681: "#d24f47",
    128682: "#c7833d",
    128683: "#e78e8d",
    128684: "#ab9b80",
    128685: "#d8807f",
    128686: "#2fade3",
    128687: "#cf7877",
    128688: "#2cace3",
    128689: "#d07877",
    128690: "#765154",
    128691: "#d27b7a",
    128692: "#806754",
    128693: "#5ea169",
    128694: "#8a653b",
    128695: "#c7706f",
    128696: "#bb8222",
    128697: "#29abe3",
    128698: "#9879c4",
    128699: "#45b5e5",
    128700: "#30aee3",
    128701: "#a7a0af",
    128702: "#1ea8e2",
    128703: "#7d8299",
    128704: "#b2aeab",
    128705: "#8494a1",
    128706: "#3cb2e4",
    128707: "#3ab1e4",
    128708: "#46b5e5",
    128709: "#53bae6",
    128716: "#3d628e",
    128720: "#9575c2",
    128721: "#df5554",
    128722: "#6a6f73",
    128747: "#61798c",
    128748: "#61798d",
    128756: "#306589",
    128757: "#ae284e",
    128758: "#547578",
    128759: "#c37754",
    128760: "#9aa48c",
    128761: "#6a587c",
    128762: "#4e7353",
    129296: "#d09e59",
    129297: "#b9923a",
    129298: "#cf8f3e",
    129299: "#c38750",
    129300: "#d5923b",
    129301: "#d3ab6f",
    129302: "#8e7a7f",
    129303: "#d9872a",
    129304: "#e1b938",
    129305: "#e7bf39",
    129306: "#e1bb39",
    129307: "#e8c13a",
    129308: "#e9c23b",
    129309: "#eabe38",
    129310: "#e2b937",
    129311: "#e3bc39",
    129312: "#a96e4a",
    129313: "#cb9bb0",
    129314: "#2db16f",
    129315: "#c17e53",
    129316: "#d08d3b",
    129317: "#de9e48",
    129318: "#e09328",
    129319: "#dba652",
    129320: "#d39a40",
    129321: "#d06a52",
    129322: "#db8766",
    129323: "#d9963c",
    129324: "#bb525b",
    129325: "#e28f2a",
    129326: "#a59b3c",
    129327: "#cfa677",
    129328: "#b38867",
    129329: "#a9a05a",
    129330: "#e3bb38",
    129331: "#b7525e",
    129332: "#92a975",
    129333: "#886950",
    129334: "#cbb683",
    129335: "#cc7829",
    129336: "#a87d3e",
    129337: "#a0856c",
    129338: "#77767a",
    129340: "#aa742f",
    129341: "#75967e",
    129342: "#966a36",
    129344: "#945527",
    129345: "#cca39b",
    129346: "#90a0a2",
    129347: "#a9b8b8",
    129348: "#87808e",
    129349: "#713a39",
    129351: "#91925c",
    129352: "#6f98ad",
    129353: "#787966",
    129354: "#cd4042",
    129355: "#b3b1b9",
    129356: "#b66976",
    129357: "#465e6b",
    129358: "#b2c839",
    129359: "#0c9ece",
    129360: "#d19756",
    129361: "#74a839",
    129362: "#3f8219",
    129363: "#b44959",
    129364: "#d99a56",
    129365: "#a78135",
    129366: "#d4a36b",
    129367: "#9e9876",
    129368: "#7d695b",
    129369: "#bca357",
    129370: "#db9c58",
    129371: "#c7d7e9",
    129372: "#d49552",
    129373: "#36aa5c",
    129374: "#bd9254",
    129375: "#e7bf7e",
    129376: "#d7993e",
    129377: "#b4a6a6",
    129378: "#690e31",
    129379: "#2197c5",
    129380: "#bc819c",
    129381: "#8e7b73",
    129382: "#027d58",
    129383: "#ce9e62",
    129384: "#c68a2b",
    129385: "#e17c78",
    129386: "#c1ab68",
    129387: "#d78a86",
    129408: "#b5202d",
    129409: "#a4743b",
    129410: "#54372e",
    129411: "#835141",
    129412: "#a091d1",
    129413: "#896452",
    129414: "#95957d",
    129415: "#784d3d",
    129416: "#939393",
    129417: "#9a7652",
    129418: "#d48347",
    129419: "#83413f",
    129420: "#b4824e",
    129421: "#5f5f5f",
    129422: "#049c51",
    129423: "#878787",
    129424: "#c63f27",
    129425: "#ab146c",
    129426: "#b87929",
    129427: "#8b8b8b",
    129428: "#8c5f3c",
    129429: "#03a759",
    129430: "#02a959",
    129431: "#72a229",
    129472: "#e4b635",
    129488: "#cc9a4d",
    129489: "#e4b339",
    129490: "#dfab36",
    129491: "#c9ad56",
    129492: "#dea536",
    129493: "#85698a",
    129494: "#e2ae69",
    129495: "#979281",
    129496: "#d49a37",
    129497: "#4b8f94",
    129498: "#a89460",
    129499: "#8e574e",
    129500: "#76903b",
    129501: "#988134",
    129502: "#837697",
    129503: "#2e7693",
    129504: "#e85ab0",
    129505: "#e65e21",
    129506: "#13a9d1",
    129507: "#c21e33",
    129508: "#964bb0",
    129509: "#dbb683",
    129510: "#24bc94",
}
```

I hope this will safe you some time.

To use it later on you can get a hold of this function. You pass the "uniCode" and get the emoji.

```
const uniToEmoji = (uni) => String.fromCodePoint(uni)
```

Answer (score -1):

**2022 Update**

I know this is a little late, but I found a really useful online code repository that identifies the most prominent colour from a provided emoji string: *[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zox2k0zrp?file=/src/hooks/useEmojiAvgColor.js)*

**Code**

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const getAvgHex = (color, total) =>
  Math.round(color / total)
    .toString(16)
    .padStart(2, 0);

export default emoji => {
  const avgColor = useMemo(
    () => {
      let totalPixels = 0;
      const colors = {
        red: 0,
        green: 0,
        blue: 0,
        alpha: 0
      };
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.font = "30px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(emoji, 0, 28);
      const { data: imageData } = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 30, 30);
      for (let i = 0; i < imageData.length; i += 4) {
        let [r, g, b, a] = imageData.slice(i, i + 4);
        if (a > 50) {
          totalPixels += 1;
          colors.red += r;
          colors.green += g;
          colors.blue += b;
          colors.alpha += a;
        }
      }
      const r = getAvgHex(colors.red, totalPixels);
      const g = getAvgHex(colors.green, totalPixels);
      const b = getAvgHex(colors.blue, totalPixels);

      return "#" + r + g + b;
    },
    [emoji]
  );
  return avgColor;
};
```